# I still don't get how to avoid the use of getBean()

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm new to Spring and I've read many guides on how to inject beans. Curiously, in every example I see, they use *getBean* in a class main method (not what I need). Also I've read many forums and questions related to how not to use *getBean* but I still can't figure out the best approach for my app.

I'm refactoring a web app that is highly coupled and without design patterns. Every business class has a corresponding DAO class, every DAO class extends a super DAO which handles the connection and other stuff. The problem here is that every DAO needs, in the constructor, some database config parameters that are being passed from the business class. What I'm trying to do is to put these parameters in a *DBConfig* bean and inject them into every DAO allowing me to create the DAO object from every business class simply, for example: *dao = new myDAO()*.

How can I inject the *DBConfig* bean into every DAO "automatically"? Should I use *getBean* in the super DAO?

Comment: If you're doing new MyDAO(), then you don't let Spring construct the object, so Spring can't inject anything into the object. You need to inject the DAOs in the business class instances.

Comment: @JB Nizet that's part of my dilemma, if I inject the DAOs in the business classes, how should I construct the business classes? business classes are constructed with new operators all over the app too.

Comment: Inject the business class instances into your UI controllers or to a global ServiceRegistry object. At some time, unless you use a Spring-aware UI framework, you will have to call `getBean()`. But it would be much better to do that i the top-most layer rather than in the DAO layer. You could use that only once to get a `ServiceRegistry` object that is injected with references to all your business class instances, which themselves are injected with the DAO instances.

Comment: I consider @JBNizet previous comments to be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your config could look like this:

```
<bean id="daoConfig1" class="com.foo.dao.DAOConfig">
    <property name="dbUrl" value="jdbc://urlForDao1" />
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="dao1" class="com.foo.dao.DAO1">
    <constructor-arg ref="daoConfig1" />
</bean>

<bean id="business1" class="com.foo.service.Business1">
    <property name="dao" ref="dao1" />
</bean>

<bean id="daoConfig2" class="com.foo.dao.DAOConfig">
    <property name="dbUrl" value="jdbc://urlForDao2" />
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="dao2" class="com.foo.dao.DAO2">
    <constructor-arg ref="daoConfig2" />
</bean>

<bean id="business2" class="com.foo.service.Business2">
    <property name="dao" ref="dao2" />
</bean>
```

Or share a single `daoConfig` instance between all `daoX` beans, if that's what you want.

You can then use the folowing to handle the business logic:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"beans.xml"});
Business1 b1 = (Business1) context.getBean("business1");
b1.doStuff();
```

Or better still, use something like Spring MVC that can wire the business beans into your controllers without needing to call `getBean()`.